# Why can immutable state variable not be initialised inside an if else statement?

Tags: solidity, constructor, immutable

I would like to initialise an immutable state variable inside an `if else` statement as follows:

```
contract Simple {
  bool immutable isNatural;

  constructor(uint number) {

    if (number != 0) {
        isNatural = true;
    } else {
        isNatural = false;
    }
  }
}
```

But I get back the following compiler error:

> TypeError: Cannot write to immutable here: Immutable variables cannot be initialized inside an if statement.

Which imo shouldn't be the case as `isNatural` would be initialised to either `true` or `false`. Is it possible to conditionally initialise an immutable variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly it's not an issue when using the ternary operator:

```
contract Simple {
  bool immutable isNatural;

  constructor(uint number) {
    isNatural = number != 0 ? true : false; 
  }
}
```